# Google Colab - OpenVPN: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)

Tags: google-colaboratory, openvpn

I got the following error when trying to use OpenVPN in Google Colab. I added sudo privilege but still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]